# C++ design question (using Model Presenter View with protected member)

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I use touchGFX which is a C++ hmi for embedded devcices. I have the following problem and I am not sure how to solve it most effective. I need to access functions in the various **StatusBar** instances from **MyModelListener** (see below).

System description:
There is a model which holds the data, the views for the hmi and some presenters which interact between the model and the views. The base classes are automatically generated, I am allowed to modify all class with "My...". All My...Pesenters are linked with the corresponding My...Views by references in both directions.

*I have some Presenters:*

class MyAPresenter : public MyModelListener;
...

class MyZPresenter : public MyModelListener;

*I have some Views belonging to the presenters:*

class MyAView: public AViewBase;
...

class MyZView: public ZViewBase;

*There is a status bar which should be used in each of the views:*

class MyStatusbar : public Statusbar;

AViewBase, ..., ZViewBase each have a **protected member instance of class MyStatusbar.**

MyAPresenter, ..., MyZPresenter **have a reference to** MyAView, ..., MyZView.

How can I **access** (many) functions of **MyStatusBar** instances (inside the MyAView...) from **MyModelListener** without introducing as many functions into each MyAView... MyZView?

The data path how status bar can be reached is:

*MyModelListener -> MyAPresenter -> MyAView -> AViewBase -> MyStatusbar*

Problems:

- I cannot access MyStatusbar instances from MyModelListener or MyAView via the AViewBase because MyStatusbar instances are declared protected within AViewBase.
- I cannot modifiy AViewBase
- I do not want to access MyStatusBar from MyAView..MyZView because I do not want to have all those many functions in each My...View.
- I do not want to write all the needed functions in each of MyAPresenter...MyZPresenter.

(All the classes are virtual)

**My solution:**

1. Make functions getStatusPtr() returning the address of the Statusbar instances in each of MyAView to MyZView. This is possible because StatusBar is defined protected but not private.
2. Make virtual getStatusPtr() in each of MyAPresenter to MyZPresenter which calls the getStatusPtr() function in MyAView to MyZView via the owned references.
3. Define a virtual getStatusPtr() returning 0 in MyModelListener.
4. Access the StatusBar from MyModelListener if the pointer is not 0. This should deliver the the status bar of A if the MyModelListener functions are called from a MyAPresenter object.
5. If the View is changed both view and presenter are destroyed and the status bar too. The statusbar thus has to be rebuilt but this is acceptable.

**Is there a better/alternative solution?**

Comment: I'd use Boost [Signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

Comment: Before I give my opinion (believe me, I'm passionate about proper MVP), does your presenter need full access to StatusBar, or just a handful of methods?  Also, do you just need the presenter to "set" stuff on the status bar, or does it need to read stuff back off of it?   What you are proposing is fairly reasonable, but I hate that you are now coupled to a specific UX framework in your presenter.

Comment: It does not need full access. The status bar only shows the time and icons, which ar made visible depending on device state. There is also no need to send data back to the presenter. The Statusbar is however destructed and rebuilt with idientical content if the screen changes.

Comment: @Eljay: I have looked into boost::signals2 and it is an interesting alternative. I need to check the speed and dependencies. It should run on an embedded system with STM32 L4 cortex M4 cpu (single threaded).